# SQL match first part of string and compare

Tags: mysql, sql, search, oracle11g

I use Oracle and MySql, so if you have any answer in both codes please let me know,

Issue:

I have 2 columns in one table called: USers

Column#1= Names
Column#2= UCNames

This list contain names that are from different sources but partially match like:

**Names**

---

**Alex** Jones **Marfex**

**UCNames**

---

**Alex** Jonnes Mike **Marfex**

I want to compare both of the columns and find match based on the following attributes:

Search on the *first* 4 for *letters* and 4 *last words* and to store in new column called: **verifiyed**

Thanks

Comment: What are you going to compare? Two columns it self or another variable with these two columns

Comment: When checking against the last 4 words your example would not verify. While it would be possible to write some sql to split it into words (not a major problem if the words are only separated by spaces with no punctuation), how do you want to treat searches when there are not 4 words (or for the first part, there are not 4 first letters)?

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the first word in a string

```
Substring(Col,1,(Locate (' ',Col + ' ')-1)) First
```

This gives you the last word in a string

```
Reverse(Substring(Reverse(Col), 1,  Locate(' ',Reverse(Col)) - 1)) Last
```

So your compare could be

```
Where 
    Substring(Col1,1,( Locate(' ',Col1 + ' ')-1)) 
    = Substring(Col2,1,( Locate(' ',Col2 + ' ')-1))
  And
    Reverse(Substring(Reverse(Col1), 1,  Locate(' ',Reverse(Col1)) - 1))
    = Reverse(Substring(Reverse(Col2), 1,  Locate(' ',Reverse(Col2)) - 1))
```

I went with words which seemed safer for what you are trying to do with just a bit more effort. If you do want to keep the 4 characters, just replace the  Locate es with 4.

Comment: If using MySQL then the SUBSTRING_INDEX function would be appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, @KickStart. Mostly SQL Server user here. Edited per your comment.

Comment: No problem. Substring_index returns the string so you do not need to use substring as well. My SQL Server is poor and my Oracle about 6 years out of date!

Comment: Thanks again. Changed to Locate then which looks like the equivalent of CharIndex.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer by @asantaballa , but using MySQL SUBSTRING_INDEX function :-

```
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(Col1, ' ', 1) = SUBSTRING_INDEX(Col2, ' ', 1)
AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(Col1, ' ', -1) = SUBSTRING_INDEX(Col2, ' ', -1)
```

or to crudely check the first 4 characters and the last 4 words:-

```
WHERE SUBSTRING(Col1, 1, 4) = SUBSTRING(Col2, 1, 4)
AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(Col1, ' ', -4) = SUBSTRING_INDEX(Col2, ' ', -4)
```